# connecting sql database to Web site on Windows azure vm

Tags: asp.net

I have a website developed in asp.net framework 4.0 which I have deployed on a windows azure vm . I want to connect the database on that vm . Sql server 2012 is installed on the vm. How do I connect my website to the database.  I'm using database for login and register for which im using membership in asp. Net.  Plz help as to wat should I change in Web configuration and other settings in iis

Answer (score 0):

Everything is the same as if you were connecting to an IP address on a normal sqlserver. On azure vpn, you just have to add the endpoint 1433 so SqlServer can connect to your vpn's IP address.

Comment: sql server is on the same machine . The application is not able to connect to the database. I need to make changes in web.config but i dont know wat changes to make . i get the follwoing error                                   The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Applications', database 'Encrypd', schema 'dbo'. this is when i try to register a user'